# ORA-01001 invalid cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an "`ORA-01001 invalid cursor`" issue I am not able to solve.
In our production environment, we have three application server and it's pointing the single Database(**Oracle 10g**).

I am receiving the "ora-01001 invalid cursor" error while calling the following procedure through the `jdbc`,

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE "GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS"(
    p_ACC_NUM IN VARCHAR2 ,
    o_PRODUCT_CODE OUT VARCHAR2 ,
    o_PRODUCT_TYPE OUT VARCHAR2 ,
    o_NATIONALITY OUT VARCHAR2 ,
    o_CUSTOMER_CAT OUT VARCHAR2 ,
    o_SERVICE_STATUS OUT VARCHAR2 ,
    o_CURR_PLAN OUT VARCHAR2 ,
    o_ERROR_CODE OUT NUMBER ,
    o_ERROR_MSG OUT VARCHAR2 )
AS
  v_count         INT;
  v_accNum        VARCHAR2(50);
  v_Product_Desc  VARCHAR2(50);
  v_IPhone_Status VARCHAR2(50);
  v_BB_Status     VARCHAR2(50);
  v_now           DATE;
BEGIN
  o_CURR_PLAN := 0;
  SELECT PRODUCT_DESC,
    PRODUCT_NAME,
    IPHONE_STATUS,
    BB_STATUS,
    PARTY_NATIONALITY,
    CUSTOMER_CAT,
    SERVICE_STATUS,
    new_postpaid_flag
  INTO v_Product_Desc,
    o_PRODUCT_TYPE,
    v_IPhone_Status,
    v_BB_Status,
    o_NATIONALITY,
    o_CUSTOMER_CAT,
    o_SERVICE_STATUS,
    o_CURR_PLAN
  FROM tbl_crm_custmaster
  WHERE account_number  = p_ACC_NUM
  AND rownum            = 1;
  IF (v_Product_Desc    = 'WS' AND v_IPhone_Status = 'N' AND v_BB_Status = 'N') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'WP'; --General Prepaid
  elsif (v_Product_Desc = 'WS' AND v_IPhone_Status = 'N' AND v_BB_Status = 'Y') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'WB'; --BlackBerry Prepaid
  elsif (v_Product_Desc = 'WS' AND v_IPhone_Status = 'Y' AND v_BB_Status = 'N') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'WI'; --IPhone Prepaid
  elsif (v_Product_Desc = 'WS' AND v_IPhone_Status = 'Y' AND v_BB_Status = 'Y') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'WP'; --General Prepaid
  elsif (v_Product_Desc = 'GS' AND v_IPhone_Status = 'N' AND v_BB_Status = 'N') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'GP'; --General Postpaid
  elsif (v_Product_Desc = 'GS' AND v_IPhone_Status = 'N' AND v_BB_Status = 'Y') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'GB'; --BlackBerry Postpaid
  elsif (v_Product_Desc = 'GS' AND v_IPhone_Status = 'Y' AND v_BB_Status = 'N') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'GI'; --IPhone Postpaid
  elsif (v_Product_Desc = 'GS' AND v_IPhone_Status = 'Y' AND v_BB_Status = 'Y') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'GP'; --General Postpaid
  elsif (v_Product_Desc = '2P' OR v_Product_Desc = '3P') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'EL'; --Landline associated with E-Life
  elsif (v_Product_Desc = 'VO') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'GL'; --Landline Postpaid
  elsif (v_Product_Desc = 'FN') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'WL'; --Landline Prepaid
  elsif (v_Product_Desc = 'HI') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'IN'; --Landline Prepaid
  elsif (v_Product_Desc = 'EV') THEN
    o_PRODUCT_CODE     := 'EV'; --Landline Prepaid
  END IF;
  o_ERROR_CODE := 0;
  o_ERROR_MSG  := 'SUCCESS';
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  o_ERROR_CODE := -1;
  o_ERROR_MSG  := 'NO REOCRDS FOUND';
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  o_ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
  o_ERROR_MSG  := SQLERRM;
END;
```

**Java Code 1:**

```
public void requestBegin(SCESession mySession) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ITraceInfo trace = mySession.getTraceOutput();
        UserDetails userDetails  = (UserDetails) mySession.getProperty(EtisalatConstants.USER_DETAILS);
        CallDetailsBean detailsBean=(CallDetailsBean) mySession.getProperty(EtisalatConstants.CALLER_DETAILS_BEAN_OBJECT);
        DwhEtisalatMethods etisalatMethods=null;
        HashMap<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String hostErrResponse = "", hostErrCode = "";
        EtaDbImpl dao = null;
        try{
            //Host Reporting Start Details
            etisalatMethods=new DwhEtisalatMethods();
            etisalatMethods.HostStartDetails(mySession, CommonMethod.generateUniqueId(), LoggingConstants.GET_CALLER_DETAILS_CRM, LoggingConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE, LoggingConstants.DATABASE);

            dao = new EtaDbImpl();
            response = dao.getCustomerDetails(userDetails.getPhoneNumber(), mySession);
            trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_DEBUG,"DB Success:");


            hostErrCode = response.get(EtisalatDbConstants.ERROR_CODE);
            hostErrResponse = response.get(EtisalatDbConstants.ERROR_MSG);
            trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_DEBUG,"ERROR_CODE:"+hostErrCode);
            trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_DEBUG,"ERROR_Response:"+hostErrResponse);


            if(hostErrResponse.equalsIgnoreCase(EtisalatDbConstants.DB_SUCCESS_MSG) || hostErrCode.equalsIgnoreCase(EtisalatDbConstants.DB_SUCCESS_CODE)){
            userDetails.setAccountNumber(response.get(EtisalatDbConstants.ACCOUNT_NUMBER));
            //userDetails.setPhoneNumber(response.get(EtisalatDbConstants.PHONE_NUMBER));
            userDetails.setProductType(response.get(EtisalatDbConstants.PRODUCT_TYPE));
            userDetails.setProductCode(response.get(EtisalatDbConstants.PROD_CODE));
            userDetails.setNationality(response.get(EtisalatDbConstants.NATIONALITY));
            userDetails.setCustomerCategory(response.get(EtisalatDbConstants.CUSTOMER_CAT));
            userDetails.setCurrPlan(response.get(EtisalatDbConstants.CURR_PLAN));
            userDetails.setServiceStatus(response.get(EtisalatDbConstants.SERVICE_STATUS));



            //Set in Project variable
            mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.APP_VARIABLES, IProjectVariables.APP_VARIABLES_FIELD_ACCOUNT_NO).setValue(userDetails.getAccountNumber());
            mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.APP_VARIABLES, IProjectVariables.APP_VARIABLES_FIELD_PRODUCT_CODE).setValue(userDetails.getProductCode());
            mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.APP_VARIABLES, IProjectVariables.APP_VARIABLES_FIELD_PRODUCT_TYPE).setValue(userDetails.getProductType());
            mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER, IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER_FIELD_ACCT_NO).setValue(userDetails.getAccountNumber());
            mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER, IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER_FIELD_CUSTOMER_CATEGORY).setValue(userDetails.getCustomerCategory());
            mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER, IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER_FIELD_NATIONALITY).setValue(userDetails.getNationality());
            mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER, IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER_FIELD_PRODUCT_CODE).setValue(userDetails.getProductCode());
            mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER, IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER_FIELD_PRODUCT_TYPE).setValue(userDetails.getProductType());
            mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER, IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER_FIELD_SERVICE_STATUS).setValue(userDetails.getServiceStatus());
            mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER, IProjectVariables.GET_CRMCUST_MASTER_FIELD_CURR_PLAN).setValue(userDetails.getCurrPlan());


            detailsBean.setAuthenticated_Type(userDetails.getProductType());
            detailsBean.setAuthenticated_number(userDetails.getAccountNumber());
            mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.FLAGS, IProjectVariables.FLAGS_FIELD_HOSTSERVICE_STATUS).setValue(EtisalatConstants.YES);
            detailsBean.setCaller_authenticated(EtisalatConstants.REPORT_YES);

            //Setting the customer segment for reporting purpose
            detailsBean.setCustomer_segment(userDetails.getCustomerSegment());

            //Setting the available products for the caller
            //detailsBean.setProduct_category(userDetails.getProductType());
            detailsBean.setProduct_category(userDetails.getProductCode());

            detailsBean.setAccount_number(userDetails.getAccountNumber());
            detailsBean.setAuthenticated_number(userDetails.getAccountNumber());
            detailsBean.setAuthenticated_Type("AUTO");
            }else if(hostErrResponse.equalsIgnoreCase(EtisalatDbConstants.DB_NO_REC_MSG) || hostErrCode.equalsIgnoreCase(EtisalatDbConstants.DB_NO_REC_CODE)){
                mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.FLAGS, IProjectVariables.FLAGS_FIELD_HOSTSERVICE_STATUS).setValue(EtisalatConstants.NO);
                trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR, "No Record Found for the account_number of '"+userDetails.getPhoneNumber()+"'");
            }else{
                throw new Exception(hostErrResponse); //Line No: 185
            }


        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            detailsBean.setCall_end_reason(EtisalatConstants.CALLEND_REASON_DBDOWN);
            mySession.getVariableField(IProjectVariables.FLAGS, IProjectVariables.FLAGS_FIELD_HOSTSERVICE_STATUS).setValue(EtisalatConstants.NO);
            trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR, "Exception : There is an issue while getting customer details "+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            mySession.setProperty(EtisalatConstants.USER_DETAILS, userDetails);
            mySession.setProperty(EtisalatConstants.CALLER_DETAILS_BEAN_OBJECT, detailsBean);

            //Host Reporting End Details
            etisalatMethods.HostEndDetails(mySession, LoggingConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE, LoggingConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE, LoggingConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE, hostErrResponse, LoggingConstants.NOT_APPLICABLE);

            response = null;
            etisalatMethods=null;
            hostErrResponse = null;
            detailsBean = null;
            trace = null;
            userDetails = null;
            dao = null;
        }
        super.requestBegin(mySession);
    }
```

**Java Code 2:**

```
public HashMap<String, String> getCustomerDetails(String acctNo, SCESession mySession){
  ITraceInfo trace = mySession.getTraceOutput();
  dataSource = (BasicDataSource)mySession.getProperty(DATASRC_IVR_DB);

  HashMap<String, String> returnhash = new HashMap<String, String>();
  //trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO, "Account number :"+acctNo.substring(acctNo.length()-4) );
  try
  {
  //logger.debug(callId+" The input is:"+hm);
  start=System.currentTimeMillis();
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO, "Start Time of GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS="+start);

  con=dataSource.getConnection();
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO, "Data source connection established");
  proc = con.prepareCall("{ call GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }");


  if(acctNo !=null && !acctNo.trim().isEmpty()){
  proc.setString(1, acctNo);
  }else{
  proc.setNull(1,  OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
  }

  proc.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
  proc.registerOutParameter(3, Types.VARCHAR);
  proc.registerOutParameter(4, Types.VARCHAR);
  proc.registerOutParameter(5, Types.VARCHAR);
  proc.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);
  proc.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);
  proc.registerOutParameter(8, Types.INTEGER);
  proc.registerOutParameter(9, Types.VARCHAR);
  try {
  if(!QueryTimeout.equalsIgnoreCase(NO))
  proc.setQueryTimeout(Integer.parseInt(QueryTimeout));
  else
  proc.setQueryTimeout(_2s);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  proc.setQueryTimeout(_2s);
  }
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_DEBUG,"Time out="+QueryTimeout);
  proc.execute();

  returnhash.put(ERROR_CODE, proc.getString(8));
  returnhash.put(ERROR_MSG, proc.getString(9));

  if(returnhash.get(ERROR_MSG).equalsIgnoreCase(DB_SUCCESS_MSG) || returnhash.get(ERROR_CODE).equalsIgnoreCase(DB_SUCCESS_CODE)){

  returnhash.put(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, acctNo);
  //returnhash.put(PHONE_NUMBER, rs.getString(2));
  returnhash.put(PROD_CODE, proc.getString(2));
  returnhash.put(PRODUCT_TYPE, proc.getString(3));
  returnhash.put(NATIONALITY, proc.getString(4));
  returnhash.put(CUSTOMER_CAT, proc.getString(5));
  returnhash.put(SERVICE_STATUS, proc.getString(6));
  returnhash.put(CURR_PLAN, proc.getString(7));


  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO,ACCOUNT_NUMBER+":"+ acctNo);
trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO,PROD_CODE+":" + proc.getString(2));
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO,PRODUCT_TYPE+":" + proc.getString(3));
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO,NATIONALITY+":" + proc.getString(4));
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO,CUSTOMER_CAT+":" + proc.getString(5));
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO,SERVICE_STATUS+":" + proc.getString(6));
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO,CURR_PLAN+":" + proc.getString(7));
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO,ERROR_CODE+":"+proc.getString(8));
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO,ERROR_MSG+":"+proc.getString(9));
  }else{
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_DEBUG, "No records found");
  }
  end=System.currentTimeMillis();
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO, "end Time of GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS="+end);
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_INFO, "Total Time of GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS="+(end-start)+"ms");
  }
  catch (SQLException e)
  {
  returnhash.put(ERROR_CODE, "03");
  returnhash.put(ERROR_MSG, e.getMessage());
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR, "SQL Exception"+e);
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  finally{
  try{
  closeResult(rs);
  closeCallableStmt(proc);
  closeConnection(con);
  }catch(SQLException e){
  returnhash.put(ERROR_CODE, "03");
  returnhash.put(ERROR_MSG, e.getMessage());
  trace.writeln(ITraceInfo.TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR, "SQL Exception while closing the Connection "+e);
  }
  if(trace != null){
  trace = null;
  }
  if(dataSource != null){
  dataSource = null;
  }
  }
  return returnhash;
  }
```

**Java code 1 method calls the Java Code 2 method.**
In java Code 1, i'm processing the data what is received from the oracle.
In java code 2, i'm calling stored procedure.

I handled the sql exception in the procedure level. If any error in the procedure, the procedure returns the oracle error code and error message as a parameter. In the java Code 2, i'm receiving the oracle error code(1001) and store that in the hashmap, after that i'm checking whether the error code is equal to 0(success).So,it prints no reocrd log. In the java Code 1, i'm receiving the hashmap. From the hashmap,i take out the error code value. if the error code is not equavalent to 0 or -1, then i'm throwing the exception what i received from the oracle(printed in trace log and stack trace log).

**Trace Log**

```
12/06/2013 06:26:35:063  INFO - EC2E4987556A7FF7DA6DEE8EEE9843FC.jvm2:/ETA_MAIN : Start Time of GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS=1371003995063
12/06/2013 06:26:35:065  INFO - EC2E4987556A7FF7DA6DEE8EEE9843FC.jvm2:/ETA_MAIN : Data source connection established
12/06/2013 06:26:35:065 DEBUG - EC2E4987556A7FF7DA6DEE8EEE9843FC.jvm2:/ETA_MAIN : Time out=2
12/06/2013 06:26:35:067 DEBUG - EC2E4987556A7FF7DA6DEE8EEE9843FC.jvm2:/ETA_MAIN : No records found
12/06/2013 06:26:35:067  INFO - EC2E4987556A7FF7DA6DEE8EEE9843FC.jvm2:/ETA_MAIN : end Time of GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS=1371003995067
12/06/2013 06:26:35:067  INFO - EC2E4987556A7FF7DA6DEE8EEE9843FC.jvm2:/ETA_MAIN : Total Time of GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS=4ms
12/06/2013 06:26:35:067 DEBUG - EC2E4987556A7FF7DA6DEE8EEE9843FC.jvm2:/ETA_MAIN : DB Success:
12/06/2013 06:26:35:067 DEBUG - EC2E4987556A7FF7DA6DEE8EEE9843FC.jvm2:/ETA_MAIN : ERROR_CODE:-1001
12/06/2013 06:26:35:067 DEBUG - EC2E4987556A7FF7DA6DEE8EEE9843FC.jvm2:/ETA_MAIN : ERROR_Response:ORA-01001: invalid cursor
12/06/2013 06:26:35:067 ERROR - EC2E4987556A7FF7DA6DEE8EEE9843FC.jvm2:/ETA_MAIN : Exception : There is an issue while getting customer details java.lang.Exception: ORA-01001: invalid cursor
```

**Stack Trace Log:**

```
 java.lang.Exception: ORA-01001: invalid cursor
at flow.DB_GetCRM_CustMaster.requestBegin(DB_GetCRM_CustMaster.java:185)
at com.avaya.sce.runtime.AppServlet.processRequest(AppServlet.java:81)
at com.avaya.sce.runtime.SCEServlet.requestHandler(SCEServlet.java:282)
at com.avaya.sce.runtime.SCEServlet.doPost(SCEServlet.java:189)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:630)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at com.avaya.sce.runtime.SCEServlet.forward(SCEServlet.java:1303)
at com.avaya.sce.runtime.Data.evaluateActions(Data.java:211)
at flow.DB_GetCallerProfileDetails.executeDataActions(DB_GetCallerProfileDetails.java:94)
```

I couldn't reproduce this issue in `SQLPlus`, it only happens from `jdbc` calls from the application server 2 and application server 3, and repeating the same call usually works (but sometimes fails couple of times before succeeding). I have not used any cursor in the procedure. Please help me on this issue.

Comment: What version are we talking about here?

Comment: Showing the Java side might help too, with more of the stack trace and how the line numbers align.

Comment: @Parthiban Your jdbc jar is compatible with Oracle 10g? I mean are you using the correct version of JDBC jar for 10g?

Comment: I'm using tomcat dbcp connection pooling(ojdbc6.jar,tomcat-dbcp.jar). This error happens sometimes only.

Comment: @Parthiban: Does this code compile? Is this the real code? Where is the variable `rs` declared and initialized? You refer to it in `closeResult(rs);`.

Comment: Are you able to call this procedure via anonymous block successfully?

Comment: "rs" is declared as class variable. i think the error is not related with the closeResult(rs) of the finally block,beacuase, the error message(SQL Exception while closing the Connection..) was not printed in the log.

Comment: So, I think Based on the log the procedure returned the "invalid cursor" error and this error is not happened often sometimes only.

Comment: I handled the sql exception in the procedure level. If any error in the procedure, the procedure returns the oracle error code and error message as a parameter. In the java Code 2,i'm receiving the oracle error code(1001) and store that in the hashmap, after that i'm checking whether the error code is equal to 0(success).So,it prints no reocrd log. In the java Code 1,i'm receiving the hashmap. From the hashmap,i take out the error code value. if the error code is not equavalent to 0 or -1,then i'm throwing the exception what i received from the oracle(printed in trace log and stack trace log).

Comment: OK, I can kind of follow that now; missed that it as a generic Exception, not an SQLException. Thanks for explaining. Hmm. If `proc` is also a class variable, is it possible that you have a race condition and you're seeing the result of a different `execute`? Are the three app servers connecting to the same user ID - just wondering if there might be a different version of your proc that you hit sometimes.

Comment: In the procedure, i have used rownum =1 condition. I suspect the problem is with the rownum condition. Because, the table contains billions of data.is it right?

Comment: @Parthiban - there won't be billions after you've filtered. If you have more than one with that `p_ACC_NUM` then the `rownum` will mean you get a random (ish) one of those, avoiding an ORA-02112. Wouldn't cause this error though, and you'd see it when calling from SQL*Plus too.

Comment: Most of the time when I have run into an invalid cursor, either someone in another process has deleted or in some cases updated a record from my cursor in another process, or more likely, I have inadvertently closed the cursor in a loop and invalidated the cursor without meaning to.  That said, I can follow your code and output up to one point.  Where is DBSuccess right before your error code coming from?  And since this seems a little old, if it's resolved, please post your fix.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe types are incorrect.. can You change signature to something like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "GET_CUSTOMER_DETAILS"(
    p_ACC_NUM IN VARCHAR2 ,
    o_PRODUCT_CODE OUT VARCHAR2 ,
    o_PRODUCT_TYPE OUT tbl_crm_custmaster.PRODUCT_NAME%type,
    o_NATIONALITY OUT tbl_crm_custmaster.PARTY_NATIONALITY%type ,
    o_CUSTOMER_CAT OUT tbl_crm_custmaster.CUSTOMER_CAT%type ,
    o_SERVICE_STATUS OUT tbl_crm_custmaster.SERVICE_STATUS%type ,
    o_CURR_PLAN OUT tbl_crm_custmaster.new_postpaid_flag%type,
    o_ERROR_CODE OUT NUMBER ,
    o_ERROR_MSG OUT VARCHAR2 ) AS
    v_count         INT;
    v_accNum        VARCHAR2(50);
    v_Product_Desc  tbl_crm_custmaster.PRODUCT_DESC%type,
    v_IPhone_Status tbl_crm_custmaster.IPHONE_STATUS%type;
    v_BB_Status     tbl_crm_custmaster.BB_STATUS%type;
    v_now           DATE;
```